# What counts as a “View” on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

How does YouTube decide that a video was "viewed"?

If a video is 5 minutes long and a viewer watches for 10 seconds, will this be counted as a view?

Comment: Post this as a answer along with the source of information, if you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What is a legitimate view?**
>   A view is an intended watch of a video where the primary purpose is to watch the video; this means that a real human being wishes to see a video, chooses which video to watch and then acts on that choice.
>   A view should be a metric that reflects genuine interest, not a gauge of how many people mistakenly or unknowingly ended up watching your video.

-- https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3399767?hl=en

This means three things:

1. Watching an autoplaying video embedded on an website doesn't count as the viewer may not have wanted to watch the video.
2. Watching an embedded video in a custom API player doesn't count as view, as the viewer may or may not have been tricked into watching the video.
3. There is no static percentage or time after which a view counts as view.